# inserting integer variable into Database

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I put this int value in our database? I've tried putting (int) and intval before $_POST but it still doesn't work? Everything else works except the conversion(?) of that int value so it can be placed in our database. Did we miss anything in the code? Thank you in advance.

```
function computeScoregrammar(){
                       // code for computing the score here
                       aver = 5; 

<?php 
 //db connection here
    $avegs = $_POST['aver'];
    $qidScores = 4; 
//below part is not yet complete for we are only trying to update a sample data in the database
    if($qidScores == 4){
      $qs = "UPDATE scores SET GrammarScore = '$avegs' WHERE applicantID = '$qidScores'";
      mysqli_query($conn,$qs);
      mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    else { 
        //else statement here
    }
      ?>
```

Comment: What do you get if you `echo $_POST['aver']`?

Comment: are those `<?php ?>` tags inside your function? or is that a different part of the code?

Comment: yes, it's a php code inside a function. We have to update/insert the score into the database everytime that button that has 'onClick=computeScoregrammar()' is clicked. Is it not okay to put a php code inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

`$qs = "UPDATE scores SET GrammarScore = $avegs WHERE applicantID = '$qidScores'";`

`$avegs` without using `''`. If you use `''`, `$avegs` will be treated as string.

Comment: still doesn't display the value of aver

Comment: What happen when you run `echo $avegs` ?
If that function is inside javascript, it is better to run AJAX call to a php script. Putting that function into javascript make user can see your code related to database and make it easy to be hacked.

Comment: yes, it is inside a javascript. When we finally display what's inside the database, it displays 0 instead of 5.

Comment: thanks for the advice, we'll try to play around some more in this since we're still new in PHP. But is $_POST['aver'] the correct way to convert(?) the int value into PHP?

Comment: `$_POST['aver']` means you get the value of element inside an html form that have property `name="aver"`. 
For example:
`<input type=text name="aver" />`
and make sure that the element is inside form that has post method
`<form method="post" />`

Comment: ohhhh I get it now why it's showing the wrong output. Thank you.

Comment: how can I pass the int from the script to php?

Comment: Javascript is run by browser while php is run by server. You can't do it. Instead, use AJAX to call a php script by passing `aver` as a POST variable. Try to learn AJAX. It will be very useful for you.

Comment: so that php script is the one that receives aver?

Comment: Yes. Look at this page [AJAX](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm)

Comment: It finally worked by using AJAX, Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING:** SQL injection, do not put this online! Use PDO or escaping (`mysqli_escape_string()`) and remove the `''`.

Comment: where do i put the mysqli_escape_string() ?

Comment: Like this: `$qs = "UPDATE scores SET GrammarScore = ".mysqli_escape_string($avegs)." WHERE applicantID = ".mysqli_escape_string($qidScores);`